# Ruby on Rails: validation_presence_of usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I am trying to use `validation_presence_of` to create a special validation case as you can see below:

```
    class Foo
       attr_accessor :a, :b

       include ActiveModel::Validations
       validates_presence_of :a, :unless => Proc.new{ |b| not b.nil? }
       validates_presence_of :b, :unless => Proc.new{ |a| not a.nil? }
    end
```

In the following code I want to it say validate `a` unless `b` is already validated, and validate `b` unless `a` is already validated.  So if `a` is already defined, I can leave `b` blank, and if `b` is already defined, then I can leave `a` blank. However if both are defined then that is also a valid answer. I just don't know why my code isn't working. I'm new to this and don't really understand where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Tumas Instance of Foo is passed to an instance block.
Also you can write a custom validation in such cases, instead of writing conditionals like this as that will give you more apt. errors.

```
class Foo
   attr_accessor :a, :b

   include ActiveModel::Validations
   validates :atleast_a_or_b_present
   def atleast_a_or_b_present
      errors.add_to_base("You must provide either a or b") if a.blank? and b.blank?  
   end

end
```

Why I suggested custom validation:

a) Consider case when both `a` and `b` both are missing. Your approach will give error to user : `a cannot be blank` , while this one will give `You must provide either a or b` and I guess second one represent the situation better.

b) In my opinion validations pertaining to two fields include to base.

c) Most important IMHO `atleast_a_or_b_present` is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because an instance of Foo is being passed to an unless block, not just an attribute. This works:

```
   class Foo
       attr_accessor :a, :b

       include ActiveModel::Validations
       validates_presence_of :a, :unless => Proc.new{ |o| not o.b.nil? }
       validates_presence_of :b, :unless => Proc.new{ |o| not o.a.nil? }
    end
```